# Trying to migrate IBM Notes data into Graph db

Tags: java, xpages

I am working in an XPages application with the OpenNTF Domino API to explore the Graph data modelling capabilities. As example I have taken the Teamroom that ships with IBM Domino.

I have defined a method to migrate responses documents into the Grap db but I get the error message: **Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method**

Here is what the method looks like:

```
private void migrateResponses(DFramedTransactionalGraph<DGraph> profilesGraph) {
    try {
        Database db = Factory.getSession().getCurrentDatabase();
        View view = db.getView("responsesOnly");
        DocumentCollection col = view.getAllDocuments();
        System.out.println("number of docs found " + col.getCount());

    for (Document response : col) {

        System.out.println("form:" + response.getFormName());
        System.out.println("id:" + response.getUniversalID());

        org.openntf.domino.ext.Document parent = response.getParentDocument();

        if (null == parent.getParentDocument()){
            //has no parent document so this parent document is a MainTopic/Post
            Post post = profilesGraph.addVertex(parent.getMetaversalID(), Post.class);
            Response vertexResponse = profilesGraph.addVertex(response.getUniversalID(), Response.class);
            vertexResponse.setSubject(response.getItemValueString("Subject"));
            Post.addResponse(vertexResponse);
        }
    }
    profilesGraph.commit();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    XspOpenLogUtil.logError(t);
}
}
```

The error occurs in line:

```
Post.addResponse(vertexResponse);
```

Here is what my Post class looks like:

```
package com.wordpress.quintessens.graph.teamroom;

import org.openntf.domino.graph2.annotations.AdjacencyUnique;
import org.openntf.domino.graph2.builtin.DVertexFrame;

import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Direction;
import com.tinkerpop.frames.Property;
import com.tinkerpop.frames.modules.typedgraph.TypeValue;

@TypeValue("post")
public interface Post extends DVertexFrame {

    @Property("$$Key")
    public String getKey();

    @Property("subject")
    public String getSubject();

    @Property("subject")
    public void setSubject(String n);

    // real edges!

    @AdjacencyUnique(label = "hasWritten", direction = Direction.OUT)
    public Iterable<Profile> getAuthors();


    @AdjacencyUnique(label = "hasReaction", direction = Direction.IN)
    public void addResponse(Response response);

    @AdjacencyUnique(label = "hasReaction", direction = Direction.IN)
    public void removeResponse(Response response);

    @AdjacencyUnique(label = "hasReaction", direction = Direction.IN)
    public Iterable<Response> getResponses();
}
```

Do you have a suggestion how I should adapt my code to make it work?

Comment: Try changing `Post` to `post`.  It looks like you are referring to the Class and not the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless OpenNTF or TinkerPop are doing some kind of magic with the supplied annotations, you are attempting to call a non-static method on an interface. Are you sure that you don't want to change:

```
Post.addResponse(vertexResponse);
```

to

```
post.addResponse(vertexResponse);
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Call the method on the instance instead of the interface. It will work fine then.